# Meaning of actions in seize block

Tags: anylogic

Would like to understand what is the difference between "On seize unit" and "On prepare unit"? I tried looking up the Anylogic help, but it does not explain anything there. Also, what does "On remove" mean?

[image: Image capture of interface]

[image: Anylogic help explanation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link "Preparation" branches into your `Seize`object. See https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcetaskstart.html#resourcetaskstart

`onSeize` is executed when a resource is being seized, i.e. before preparation (if you have a prep branch)

`opPrerareUnit` is executed when the seized resource finished its prep branch and is just about to start servicing the agent.

You can always test yourself by using some `traceln` texts in those code fields to see when and how they execute